# Can we login to putty with FTP details

Tags: ftp, putty

I tried to login with putty to the Server with FTP details Hostname, Username and Password. But it says Access Denied when i entered the Paassword.

For my another Website i entered my hostname and click open in putty, it shows "Network Error: Connection timeout".

But the 2 sites can be opened in FTP client like Smart FTP. To access through putty shall i need any permission or what else may be the problem.

Where i can find Putty Details i.e., Username and Password to login to putty in SSL. I need to execute MYsql insttruction, do File transfer etc., Please show me link to learn some commands.

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putty is an SSH/Telnet client not an FTP client - different protocol, different TCP port. FTP is typically exposed since it's less risk - SSH can be much more dangerous and I would suspect blocked if you're seeing a connection timeout message.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use Putty to login to an FTP server you need to do it manually. You need to set a RAW connection to port 21. Once connected you need to send USER, followed by username, and PASS followed by the password.
You can find more info on RFC959 http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html

If you want to try another ftp software, give a shot to WinSCP.

Comment: Thanks, I can login with Port 21 and Set RAW connection. Where i can find more details about it to use commands to upload files etc.,.

Comment: You cannot access MySQL using putty, the protocol is not text based, like the ftp or http, but it is binary based

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to create a folder called billing and place all the putty exe's and batch files.

```
echo off
echo Starting PSFTP and Logging Into FTPSITE.ORG
psftp.exe username@FTP.org -pw "PASSWORD" -b "C:\BILLING\SITE.CMD"
echo   %d%%t%
move /y "C:\Interface\Charges\BILLING.EXP" "C:\Interface\Charges\Sent\BILLING%d%%t%.EXP"
echo Done Uploading Billing Results and Moving Files
exit
```